# PHP regex needs to filter other characters between words

Tags: php, regex

I am new to PHP regex. Just started playing with it.
I want to accept only words (it could be 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 etc), but should accept only words, no special characters, no numbers in between these words.

for example a Name: "John williams lewis"

Regex should reject if a name has something like "John 123 williams -$ Lewis"

I tried using as `[\w\s]+` , this regex able to accept more words, but not understanding how to filter other characters in between words.

I am sorry if it is a dumb query.

Comment: Please, elaborate on "special characters". Would "Jöhn Wíllìamŝ Lẽwiş" be okay or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*$
```

You can try this.Anchors `^$` will make sure you dont have partial matches.

You can use `^[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z])*$` if you want to match names separated by `space`.

Comment: Just a doubt, why cannot just use as : [a-zA-Z ]*$  , here : https://regex101.com/r/sV9sP8/1

Comment: @John that will match `empty strings`.If you use just `^[a-zA-Z ]+$` then it will match a string consisting of only `spaces.`

Comment: Another query: I had  string like John John James James, where John John  is one name and James James is another name, how do I differentiate with ur regex code?

Comment: @John there is no way to do it.Regex can never know when a name ends or another starts.It can be done if you fix the length like a name can only be of two words or something

Answer (score 0):

`\w` accept all word characters include digits and alphabets, instead you can use `[a-zA-Z]` if you just want to match alphabets. and for accepting the desire result you can add white-space matcher `\s` to your character class :

```
[a-zA-Z\s]+
```

Also you can use negated character class to refuse of match some characters for example the following regex will match any thing except digits :

```
[^\d]+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\s]+$
```

This will accept only Alphabets(small or capital both) and space only.